# Separate a JavaScript array by unique keywords

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying to interact with an array by looking for keywords and split the key which contains them into two or more keys, one containing the keyword and the other(s) with the beginning and the end of what it was before.

For example, given I have the Keywords "cat" and "dog"

`var arrayinput = ["acat", "zdogg", "dogs"];`

The desidered output would be

`[ "a", "cat", "z", "dog", "g", "dog", "s" ]`

I had been making Regular-Expressions containing a pattern of my keywords and using `.match()`.

However, things like "acat" will return a valid match to the keyword "cat". Given "acat" I need "a" to be seen separately and then "cat" to be seen as valid.

Comment: When you match, you need to use unshift / splice to add the element to the array index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/3jtqc2s2/

```
arrayinput = [].concat.apply([], arrayinput.map(function (v) {
    return v.split(/(cat|dog)/);
})).filter(function(v) {
 return v !== "";
});
```

This will also detect multi cat or dog terms.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `Array.forEach` and `String.match` functions:

```
var arrayinput = ["acat","zdogg","dogs"],
    result = [],
    matches;

    arrayinput.forEach(function(word){
        matches = word.match(/^(\w*)(cat|dog)+(\w*)$/i);
        if (matches[1]) result.push(matches[1]);
        if (matches[2]) result.push(matches[2]);
        if (matches[3]) result.push(matches[3]);

    });

    console.log(result);
    // the output:
    ["a", "cat", "z", "dog", "g", "dog", "s"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using the standard for loop:

```
    var result = [];
    for(var currentValue of arrayinput) {
        var obj = currentValue.split(/(cat|dog)/);
        result = result.concat(obj.filter(function(v) {return v != '';}));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Three related solutions using coercion to a string, regex replacement, and coercion back to an array. None use looping. Not saying it's elegant, efficient or recommended, just that it's possible.

```js
var arrayinput = ["acat", "zdogg", "dogs"];

document.write(
  arrayinput
    .join(" ")                            // coerce to space-separated string
    .replace(/(cat|dog)/g, " $1 ")        // flank all keywords with spaces
    .replace(/ +/g, " ")                  // collapse multiple spaces to one
    .trim()                               // remove leading or trailing spaces
    .split(" ")                           // re-create array, splitting at spaces
);

document.write("<br />");

document.write(
  arrayinput
    .join(" ")                            // coerce to space-separated string
    .replace(/\B(cat|dog)/g, " $1")       // precede embedded keyword-starts with spaces
    .replace(/(cat|dog)\B/g, "$1 ")       // follow embedded keyword-ends with spaces
    .split(" ")                           // re-create array, splitting at spaces
);

document.write("<br />");

document.write(
  arrayinput
    .toString()                           // coerce to comma-separated string
    .replace(/([^,])(cat|dog)/g, "$1,$2") // precede embedded keyword-starts with commas
    .replace(/(cat|dog)([^,])/g, "$1,$2") // trail embedded keyword-ends with commas
    .split()                              // re-create array, splitting at commas
);
```